# Problem parsing a json file using Java and mongodb.DBObject

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a Json file but I am getting this error:

```
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:  ^{"id":"92824502157","name":"Eric CX"}
```

It points in the beggining of the string and indicates that  there is a space.I checked the file and there is no space in front of the json string.

Comment: Can you show us the code using for parsing and full error log.